# IIS Windows Authentication from a foreign (trusted) domain 401 error

Tags: windows, iis, web-applications, trusted

Describe the Bug
IIS Windows Authentication does not work with users from a trusted domain.i get authentication error 401 1
.

When trying to log in my webapplication with a foreign user i get a authentication unauthorized the user are in the right groups the password are correct, iam trying insife my web server , windows athentification is paramater with the provider negotiate and ntlm .
Expected Behavior
Users from trusted domains should be able to authenticate just like users from the local domain, in this setup it works for users from the local domain but not for users from the foreign domain.

Comment: This isn't a question for developer focus site like this, as the actual login is controlled by the underlying Windows components and Active Directory, a typical topic for server/domain administrators. You might be able to enable login audit log entries in Windows event log to get more information on the failed one (direct cause of 401.1) but only your domain administrators can help you resolve them, not likely anyone here.

Comment: You need more information to analyze your problem, try using failed request tracing to see details about 401 error, this will generate detail log file, which will help you to identify the problem.